# Sendmail Server Authentication: Certificate based: Error

Tags: authentication, sendmail, certificate-authority

I have configured my setup for a server certificate based authentication. 
Both Server and Client are sendmail systems and both have the same set of certificates.

However when client communicated with the server, i get the following error:
**403 4.7.0 authentication failed**

**Access file contents:**
TLS_Srv:mx3.domaintest.com VERIFY 
TLS_Rcpt:       VERIFY:CI:/O=Sendmail/OU=Sendmail+20Server/CN=debian/Email=admin@debian

**db file created using following command:**
makemap hash access.db < access

**Client sendmail Logs:**

> May 13 03:38:26 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS: CRLFile missing
>   May 13 03:38:26 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, init=1
>   May 13 03:38:26 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, start=ok
>   May 13 03:38:26 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, info: fds=7/6, err=2
>   May 13 03:38:27 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS: TLS cert verify: depth=0 /O=Sendmail/OU=Sendmail Server/CN=debian/emailAddress=admin@debian, state=0, reason=self signed certificate
>   May 13 03:38:27 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, info: fds=7/6, err=2
>   May 13 03:38:27 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, get_verify: 18 get_peer: 0x81e7a60
>   May 13 03:38:27 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx3.domaintest.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
>   May 13 03:38:27 sendmail[5052]: STARTTLS=client, cert-subject=/O=Sendmail/OU=Sendmail+20Server/CN=debian/emailAddress=admin@debian, cert-issuer=/O=Sendmail/OU=Sendmail+20Server/CN=debian/emailAddress=admin@debian, verifymsg=self signed certificate
>   May 13 03:38:27 sendmail[5052]: ruleset=tls_server, arg1=FAIL, relay=mx3.domaintest.com, **reject=403 4.7.0 authentication failed**

**Server Logs:**

> May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: STARTTLS=read, info: fds=8/4, err=2
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: STARTTLS=read, info: fds=8/4, err=2
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: r4D73R1p003966: from=, size=706, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<1368405535.7035.26.camel@client1.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=domain.com [client_ip]
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: r4D73R1p003966: --- 250 2.0.0 r4D73R1p003966 Message accepted for delivery
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: STARTTLS=read, info: fds=8/4, err=2
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: r4D73R1q003966: <-- QUIT
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: r4D73R1q003966: --- 221 2.0.0 domaintest.com closing connection
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: STARTTLS=server, SSL_shutdown not done
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3966]: poststats: /var/lib/sendmail/sendmail.st: No such file or directory
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3970]: r4D73R1p003966: to=, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30999, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3970]: poststats: /var/lib/sendmail/sendmail.st: No such file or directory
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3970]: r4D73R1p003966: done; delay=00:00:00, ntries=1
>   May 13 02:03:41 domaintest sm-mta[3970]: poststats: /var/lib/sendmail/sendmail.st: No such file or directory

Where am i going wrong here??

In the client sendmail.cf file, i can see that the following rule is getting hit:
**STLS_connection**

> **authentication required: give appropriate error
>
>     other side did authenticate (via STARTTLS)**
>   R <> OK             $@ OK
>   R  OK           $:   
>   R  OK        $:   
>   R  $*          $:   
>   R         $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " authentication required"
>   **R  FAIL   $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " authentication failed"**
>   R  NO     $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " not authenticated"
>   R  NOT    $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " no authentication requested"
>   R  NONE   $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " other side does not support STARTTLS" 
>    R  $+     $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " authentication failure " $4
>   R               $:    $>max $&{cipher_bits} : $&{auth_ssf}
>   R  $-           $:    $(arith l $@ $4 $@ $2 $)
>   R  TRUE       $#error $@ $2 $: $1 " encryption too weak " $4 " less than " $3
>   R  $*         $: 
>   R                    $@ OK
>   R                 $:  
>   R < $+ ++ $+ >             
>   R $+                     $@ $>"TLS_req" $3 $|

Please guide!

Regards

Comment: What file permissions do you have on the self-signed certs? Is TLS working when communicating with other systems? Are these both internal systems?  If so, do you have any requirements for outbound communication (e.g. SMTP auth)?

Comment: I think there was some issue in the certificates. I generated a new set. However, when i use this new set, i am getting verify=ok

Now i tried to make this fail. So in access file, i changed the string (Certificate Issuer) so that it wont match with the one provided by the server.

As per my understanding, it should have failed. yet it went through.

How do i configure client so that if the  Cert Issuer/Subject string does not match with that provided by server, then should not send across to sender?

Comment: yes TLS is shown. yes both are internal system. Yes the server will be responsible for communicating with the internet (destination) mail servers, but before that my local client and the server should authenticate. Not to use the SMTP AUTH mechnism. Only via certificate and that too server based

Comment: If the certificate is self signed, has the client accepted the certificate?

Comment: How to check this? i guess in client logs, i should get verify=Ok if its accepted. rt? With new set of certificates, am getting Ok.